# SonarQube not detecting removed issues

Tags: sonarqube

In the documentation of the SonarQube issue lifecycle (https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Issue+Lifecycle) one of the two possible resolutions is:

- **Removed** - set automatically when either the related coding rule or the file is no longer available. The rule may not be available either because it has been removed from the profile or because the underlying plugin has been uninstalled. **The file could be unavailable because it has been removed from the project, moved to a different location or renamed.**

Even after analyzing dozens of commits of an open-source project, in which files were clearly renamed and moved, the Removed count is still zero.

Does anybody understand why this is? Shouldn't the counter increase?

Answer (score 2):

SonarQube detects file move, so  when E.G. `A.java` is moved to `B.java`, its issues will move with it.

Removed, as described in the docs, is used when the rule no longer applies. Try removing a high issue count rule from your profile and reanalyzing; you should see the Removed number increase.

Comment: Thanks @G. Ann! We did a test a while ago and SQ did not detect a file move when the file contents were modified at the same time. Or is this fixed in the meantime?

Comment: Can you quantify "a while ago"?

Comment: About half a year ago. Could this be a problem in older versions and solved in newer versions?

Comment: Kinda depends on which version you were on 6mo ago @mircealungu. We have done some work on this. If its still a problem in the latest version (currently 7.2) you should open a thread here: https://community.sonarsource.com

Comment: Finally got hold of my collaborator. We were using 6.4 at the time.